The event waited for never came?
using headless_chrome = "1.0.10" scraping web pages, so faced with ~every second link not waited with Err in match: The event waited for never came
error occurs at Err(load_error.into())
let active: Result<&Tab, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> = match tab.navigate_to(&link) {
    Ok(unloaded_page) => match unloaded_page.wait_until_navigated() {
        Ok(loaded_page) => {
            Ok(loaded_page)
        }
        Err(load_error) => {
            println!("couldn't waited {}, {load_error}", &link);
            Err(load_error.into())
        }
    },
    Err(open_error) => {
        println!("couldn't open {}, {open_error}", &link);
        Err(open_error.into())
    }
};

How to resolve it ? Is it depends of not really right way using wait_until_navigated in my case ?

you could use  a simple polling mechanism to wait for an element.

You should not be using wait_until_navigated(). navigate_to() already waits for that.
